# How to set agent pool using matrix variable in Azure Pipelines when pool is an object?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Consider the following Azure Pipelines YAML:

```yaml
- job: Test
  strategy:
    matrix:
      linux:
        pool:
          name: AzurePipelines-EO
          demands:
          - ImageOverride -equals AzurePipelinesUbuntu20.04compliantGPT
          os: Linux
      windows:
        pool: VSEngSS-MicroBuild2022-1ES
      mac:
        pool:
          name: Azure Pipelines
          vmImage: macOS-12
          os: macOS

  pool: $(pool)
```

Notice how each pool value is a unique shape. Note that each pool variable value is a valid argument for `job.pool`.

But this fails because matrix variables are only allowed to be scalar values, but the pool variable defined for linux and mac are yaml 'mappings' (i.e. objects) instead of strings.

I can't think of how to redefine this using strings such that it'll work as intended. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix variables indeed need to be scalar values (e.g., strings) and cannot directly accept mappings or objects,
The use of script steps in the example was merely to illustrate what actions might take place within each job tailored to the specific environment, rather than as a method to dynamically select the pool.

```
jobs:
- job: TestLinux
  pool:
    name: AzurePipelines-EO
    demands:
    - ImageOverride -equals AzurePipelinesUbuntu20.04compliantGPT
  steps:
  - script: echo Running tests on Linux

- job: TestWindows
  pool: VSEngSS-MicroBuild2022-1ES
  steps:
  - script: echo Running tests on Windows

- job: TestMac
  pool:
    name: Azure Pipelines
    vmImage: macOS-12
  steps:
  - script: echo Running tests on macOS
```

Comment: Ya, that's what I was afraid of. In my case, there is a lot of other variables set on the `job`. I know I can move the `steps` into its own template file that I can then import and reuse. But many other complex properties set on the job I don't think I can just import via template. So I was really hoping to keep the matrix syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out a way to get this working with an expression.

The best solution I can find is to split out your matrix into two matrixes in 2 separate jobs, and then you can reference the rest of your build steps in a template so you do not have to duplicate them.

### `main.yaml`:

```
jobs:
- job: MicrosoftHostedAgents
  displayName: Microsoft-hosted Agents
  strategy:
    matrix:
      ubuntu:
        poolName: 'ubuntu-latest'
        exampleVariable: '1.0'
      windows:
        poolName: 'windows-latest'  
        exampleVariable: '2.0'
  pool:
    vmImage: $(poolName)
  steps:
  - template: build-steps.yaml
    parameters:
      poolName: $(poolName)
      exampleVariable: $(exampleVariable)

- job: SelfHostedAgents
  displayName: Self-hosted Agents
  strategy:
    matrix:
      self-hosted:
        poolName: 'Default'
        exampleVariable: '3.0'
  pool:
    vmImage: $(poolName)
  steps:
  - template: build-steps.yaml
    parameters:
      poolName: $(poolName)
      exampleVariable: $(exampleVariable)
```

### `build-steps.yaml`:

```
parameters:
  - name: poolName
  - name: exampleVariable

steps:
- powershell: |
    Write-Host "${{ parameters.poolName }}: ${{ parameters.exampleVariable }}"
```

### Screenshot output:

Note that my self-hosted job was skipped because in my test Azure Devops, I do not have any self hosted agents available.

[image]